# How can I tail error logs on centos 6 server for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, nginx, digital-ocean

I have created and built a server on Digitalocean and its a centos 6 server with nodejs running and rails installed on top of it. Its has nginx and passenger running together and I am deploying with capistrano to ease that process with postgres as the production db to use. Everything is installed okay and the db is set up.

I have deployed the site and the capistrano deploy worked fine with no errors but when I go to the staging site it has an error. I am trying to get the logs for this but I cannot seem to find them. I have tried the /log/staging.log file and I have set the /environments/staging.rb file to look like this:

```
PopupHub::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

# Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  SitemapGenerator.verbose = false

  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
  config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
  config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/*)

end
```

When I go to use `tail -f log/staging.log` I get nothing but information about a migration with no logging when I refresh the page on the apps ip address.

can anyone help me to see where I can locate the logs properly or get them working?

Comment: Are you sure you're running in staging environment? How did you start your server?

Comment: well after deploying my site via capistrano it gave the error so i assume it is staging thats running

Comment: Its okay found the error logs in /opt/nginx/logs/error.log so have done tail -f /opt/nginx/logs/error.log and its working now :)